# How can we display Time in our Game cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I tried to use :

DelayTime*
Second Schedule() function

but nothing happened.

I just want to display my time in HUD Layer.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Update a time variable in a scheduled function, and use a label to display its value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update a time variable in a scheduled  function with 1 second delay. Make a counter increase on each call of the function and calculate time like following:

```
HH = Counter /3600;
MM = (Counter %3600)/60;
SS: ((counter%3600)%60);
```